# Migration from singletone to java ee injection

Tags: java, caching, jboss, dependency-injection, jboss-weld

I have Jboss AS 6.1 and war and sar applications on it. I use cassandra. So i need managers to access database and cache database objects for fast access. 
So i did it in such a way:

```
    public class AsaBlackSubsManager extends OperatorsCache<AsaBlackSubs> {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AsaBlackSubsManager.class);
    private final static String CF_NAME = "asa_black_subs";
    private static AsaBlackSubsManager instance = null;
    private MsisdnManager msisdnManager;

    private AsaBlackSubsManager() {
        reload();
        msisdnManager = new MsisdnManager();
    }

    public static AsaBlackSubsManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AsaBlackSubsManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public List<AsaBlackSubs> list() {
        final List<AsaBlackSubs> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final Statement query = QueryBuilder.select().from(CF_NAME);
        final ResultSet rows = BasicManager.getInstance().getSession().execute(query);
        for (final Row row : rows) {
            if (row != null && row.getString("name") != null) {
                final AsaBlackSubs subs = new AsaBlackSubs();
                subs.setId(row.getUUID("id").toString());
                subs.setName(row.getString("name"));
                subs.setOperatorId(row.getString("operatorId"));
                subs.setParams(row.getString("params"));
                subs.setDescription(row.getString("description"));
                subs.setParentId(row.getString("parentId"));
                subs.setOwner(row.getString("owner"));
                list.add(subs);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(list, new HierarchyObjectComparator());
        return list;
    }

    public String create(final AsaBlackSubs subs) {
        if (subs.getId() == null) {
            final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            subs.setId(uuid.toString());
        }
        final Insert query = QueryBuilder.insertInto(CF_NAME)
                .value("id", UUID.fromString(subs.getId()))
                .value("name", subs.getName())
                .value("operatorId", subs.getOperatorId())
                .value("params", subs.getParams())
                .value("description", subs.getDescription())
                .value("owner", subs.getOwner())
                .value("parentId", subs.getParentId());
        BasicManager.getInstance().getSession().execute(query);
        reload();
        return subs.getId();
    }

}
```

Also i have abstract cache class where my objects are cached and sorted by operator.

```
public abstract class OperatorsCache<T extends OperatoredObject> {

    protected List<T> cache;
    protected Map<String, List<T>> mapByOperator;

    public abstract List<T> list();

    public void reload() {
        cache = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(list());
        mapByOperator = cache.parallelStream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OperatoredObject::getOperatorId));
    }

    public List<T> cachedList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(cache);
    }

    public List<T> cachedListByOperator(final String operatorId) {
        return mapByOperator.getOrDefault(operatorId, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public T get(final String id) {
        final Optional<T> any = cache
                .parallelStream()
                .filter(obj -> obj.getId().equals(id))
                .findAny();
        return any.isPresent() ? any.get() : null;
    }

}
```

So in this way i can access my class from war and from sar, from any place and cache will be the same. There will be only one object of this cache. The manager class itself is in the sar. 
It is a rather good way, but i know about weaknesses of singleton, so i decided to replace my singleton with weld dependency injection, which is integrated in Jboss. I did it in such way: remove private constructor and getInstance() method and added a @ApplicationScope annotation. And in my web classes i just annotate @Inject. Like this:

```
public class CreateAsaSubsb extends BaseAction {


    @Inject
    AsaBlackSubsManager manager;

    public void perform(final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response, final JSONObject jsonObject) throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException
...
```

But when i am trying to start all this, war application does not start and i have exceptions like this:
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [AsaBlackSubsManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject

I was searching for answers a couple of days, but i still can figure out: What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 6 is a Java EE 6 app server. According to the [CDI 1.0 spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/packagingdeployment.html#beanarchive) (which is part of Java EE 6), you have to put a beans.xml file in your archive : in the WEB-INF/ directory for a war, in the META-INF/ directory for an jar.

Comment: I have put beans.xml in war and in sar and in jar in a sar. It does not help.